# Lost resource after edit in design mode visual studio 2012

Tags: visual-studio-2012

I'm facing this strange behavior of visual studio 2012. Whenever I made any changes in design mode, all resources of that form get lost. Does anyone know how to fix this bug?

Comment: Does it happen only in one project? Does cleaning the project and deleting all assemblies is of any help?

Comment: @Frederik.L Sorry for late response. I don't know if it happen or only this project or not since this is the first project we're working with Visual Studio 2012. But this behavior doesn't happen in some tiny project that I create to test some code. Cleaning and deleting all assemblies doesn't help at all